# MSBuild Vs Visual Studio - Differences in compilation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I'm attempting to set up a Continuous Integration process for a legacy VB.Net ASP.Net Forms application, using Visual Studio 2015 and an on premises TFS 2013 server. However, I'm failing to get a Build Definition to successfully build my application.

It's a XAML Build Definition, which triggers happily on every TFS check in, but has so far failed to build the application, due to errors compiling a component project with Property-related errors like `'Extended Properties cannot be initialized'`.

The projects all compile happily within Visual Studio, so I'm guessing these errors are actually due to the version of the `vbc.exe` compiler, or the compiler options being used by MSBuild?

I've tried to pass the same compiler settings used in the project to the MSBuild arguments (see below), but without success.

```
/p:OptionStrict=false /p:OptionInfer=false /p:OptionExplicit=true /p:OptionCompare=binary
```

The main application project has the following ToolsVersion, specified in the project file, but could Visual Studio actually using a later version (14 or 15?) which MSBuild isn't?

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0"
```

Any suggestions of why this project would build perfectly in Visual Studio, but not in the Build Definition would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is installed on your build agent?

Comment: The build agent is the TFS server that contains the Build Definition right? If so, it isn't installed on there, but I did copy over missing v12.0 references to the machine earlier to the following location: C:\Program `Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0`. The compilers were already present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin`

Comment: VS2015 uses MSBuild 14, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 and https://chocolatey.org/packages/microsoft-build-tools Do you have that on your agent machine?

Comment: Thanks Lex, that sounds like it could well be the problem. I've installed the tools on our TFS server (and restarted everything), but am still getting the same issue. However in the MSBuild log the path to vbc.exe is still v12 `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Vbc.exe /noconfig /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections....`Do you know how I can force MSBuild to use the v14 vbc.exe?

Comment: @LexLi Ah, as specified on this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx I've now found the `/toolsversion` or `\tv` argument which seems to have forced v14.0 of the compiler successfully, many thanks. (Feel free to write up your comment as an Answer, and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I commented, the tricky part here is to determine the right MSBuild tooling version and then use it in the right way.

First it would be hard to remember the MSBuild version number for their Visual Studio releases. You can use Google and below is just some for reference,

- Visual Studio 2015 - MSBuild 14
- Visual Studio 2017 - MSBuild 15

Make sure they exist on the machine who executes the build.

Second, you might need to override the tooling version ([per this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks again Lex. I'm setting up MSBuild definitions for the first time and I've now bumped into a different issue caused by not having the VS2015 SDK / VS 2015 itself installed on the build agent, and I'm also starting to find advice about not putting TFS, Build Controllers and Build Agents on the same server (which I was hoping to do). Time to do some more reading before installing anything else....